# Small projects for learning to code javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, projects

I want to be employable as a Front End Web Developer but can only write `CSS`/`HTML` along with a little bit of `Jquery` (on a tangent: moderate amount of `PHP`) but no understanding of `Javascript`.

The current skillset was learnt quite fast (9 months) through programming a website.. so I think projects are the best way to learn.

Any ideas on some simple projects/resources to learn and practice `Javascript`? I like Project Euler but the site only focuses on maths - maybe similar styled questions targeted at user interaction and core capabilities?

Comment: Start reading http://eloquentjavascript.net/.

Comment: Liking the look of that link, thanks

Comment: Check out some projects on http://codepen.io/ and see if you can play around with them, or understand them.  Heres some javascript ones: http://codepen.io/search?q=javascript&limit=all&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: Thanks Hazaart.. I've used codecademy (and khanacademy) a couple times but find them slow, simplistic and the linear approach difficult to learn from. If they made the tasks more obscure with some pointers, that'd make it more interesting (as opposed to filling out a template).. but then again automated rating systems have their limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know enough, go apply for positions with companies even though you may only know a small amount, you will learn best by having projects to tackle on the job. Any organization that hires you will know your experience through the interview process.

If you do not do this and feel you need more experience, create a project for yourself or someone else, build a website, teach yourself how to build a .JS slideshow for example.

A decent book on JS that I have used is `http://ineasysteps.com/products-page/programming/javascript-in-easy-steps-5th-edition/`

You can try this book as well `http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/`

If you are into onlin learning try Code Academy `http://www.codecademy.com/` or Code School `https://www.codeschool.com/` or Tree House `http://teamtreehouse.com/` courses

Comment: Useful info, thanks :-) Might just take the plunge and apply for a job too!